# Overlapping cycle decomposition

Tags: graph-theory

Is there an algorithm to decompose a graph $G=(V,E)$ into all overlapping $m$-cycles? How is such a decomposition called?

As an example have a look at graph [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e28Z5.png)

[image: simple graph with 6 vertices]

When decomposing into 3-cycles I want to extract the following subgraphs:

- $H_1=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$
- $H_2=\{v_1,v_3,v_4\}$
- $H_3=\{v_1,v_4,v_5\}$
- $H_4=\{v_1,v_3,v_5\}$
- $H_5=\{v_3,v_4,v_5\}$

Comment: This doesn't seem like a decomposition: some edges are in many of your cycles, and some edges (unsurprisingly) are in none at all. Do you just want to find all the $m$-cycles in the graph?

Comment: Yes this is probably not a decomposition, how is finding all $m$-cycles called?

Comment: It's called "finding all $m$-cycles" :)

Comment: haha should have guessed that